# How to access log files produced during docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, yarn-v2

I have a Dockerfile like this in my application source code

```
FROM node:latest

USER node
WORKDIR /work

COPY --chown=node .yarn/releases/* /work/.yarn/releases/
COPY --chown=node package.json yarn.lock .yarnrc.yml /work
RUN yarn install --immutable && yarn cache clean

# Copy source code
COPY --chown=node tsconfig* nx.json jest* /work/
COPY --chown=node apps/backend /work/apps/backend
COPY --chown=node libs /work/libs

# Copy app config
COPY --chown=node config.*.yml .env /work/

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]
```

I use this command to build the image

```
docker build -t me/myimage .
```

When build locally on my machine, it works fine. But when building on CI server, I got this error in the `RUN yarn install --immutable && yarn cache clean` step

```
#9 80.01 ➤ YN0009: │ cypress@npm:12.14.0 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /tmp/xfs-c9cb8a8a/build.log)
#9 80.01 ➤ YN0009: │ esbuild@npm:0.17.19 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /tmp/xfs-b24e1b31/build.log)
#9 80.01 ➤ YN0009: │ @parcel/watcher@npm:2.0.4 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /tmp/xfs-deb3355a/build.log)
#9 80.01 ➤ YN0009: │ protobufjs@npm:6.11.3 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /tmp/xfs-4190fa5b/build.log)
#9 80.01 ➤ YN0007: │ nx@npm:16.3.2 [c2878] must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
#9 80.08 ➤ YN0009: │ nx@npm:16.3.2 [c2878] couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /tmp/xfs-a4dbfcc2/build.log)
#9 80.11 ➤ YN0007: │ amp-test-e2e@workspace:. must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
#9 80.17 ➤ YN0009: │ amp-test-e2e@workspace:. couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /tmp/xfs-aaad7563/build.log)
#9 80.17 ➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 21s 420ms
#9 80.19 ➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 1m 20s
#9 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c yarn install --immutable && yarn cache clean" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I want to find the `/tmp/xfs-aaad7563/build.log` to see what is causing the error but it seems the file cannot be found on the host machine.

Is there a way I can access these files?